# ASP.NET Core Web API - Error CS1501: No overload for method 'All' takes 2 arguments in Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I am trying to implement Fluent Validation in ASP.NET Core-5 Web API. I have Application User from IdentityDbContext:

```
public class CreateAdminUserCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateAdminUserCommand>
{
    private readonly IDDMDbContext _dbContext;
    //public CreateAdminUserCommandValidator(IDDMDbContext dbContext)
    public CreateAdminUserCommandValidator()
    {
        //_dbContext = dbContext;
        RuleFor(u => u.UserName)
            .MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("Username must not exceed 100 characters.")
            .MustAsync(BeUniqueName).WithMessage("The specified Username already exists.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("User Name field is required. ERROR!")
            .Matches(@"^[\S]+$").WithMessage("No Space Required. ERROR!");
    }
    private async Task<bool> BeUniqueName(string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //TODO: Control by uppercase and CultureInfo
        return await _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.All(x => x.UserName != name, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I want to validate UserName to be Unique using BeUniqueNam, but I got this error:

> Error CS1501  No overload for method 'All' takes 2 arguments

and it highlights **All**

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Cancellation token would be for an Async method.  Is there an AllAsync(...) method instead?  If not, then you only have .All which isn't async, so you can't pass the token in as it is Synchronous.

Comment: @DanielLorenz - AllAsync is not available. So I removed Cancellation token, async and await as shown here:           private Task<bool> BeUniqueName(string name)
        {
            return _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.All(x => x.UserName != name);
        }        but the error becomes       Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>'

Comment: Since .All has no async method, you can't really return async Task<bool>. Just. return bool directly and get rid of the await and cancellation token.